# Understanding a proof that $Y_T\leq E(Y_N | F_T)$ for a submartingale $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I'm struggling to understand the proof of Lemma 2 in [these notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~pfitz/downloads/courses/winter05/math280b/doob.pdf). Am I correct in interpreting $E(Y_N; A)$ as $E(Y_N 1_A)$? It seems to me that, rewriting either end of the chain of inequalities as integrals, all we've proven here is that for $A\in F_T$:

$$\int_A E(Y_N|F_T)dP\geq \int_A Y_T dP$$

But an inequality for all integrals over measurable sets doesn't imply the inequality is true almost everywhere.

Comment: Rewrite it $$\int_A (E(Y_N \mid F_T) - Y_T) \, dP \geq 0$$ and consider $A := \{E(Y_N \mid F_T)-Y_T <0\}$.

Comment: @saz I see! So in fact, an inequality over integrals on a certain sigma algebra $F$ *is* sufficient to establish the inequality a.e. as long as the functions in question are $F$-measurable.